# Sending hyeprlink text through WhatsApp API - php

Tags: php, html, whatsapp

I try to send url via php script with WhatsApp Api, I used the blog: http://blog.philippheckel.com/2013/07/07/send-whatsapp-messages-via-php-script-using-whatsapi/

I could send plain text to any number using the API call. 
for example script(in PHP) is:

```
$w = new WhatsProt($userPhone, $userIdentity, $userName, $debug);
$w->Connect();
$w->LoginWithPassword($password);
$w->sendMessage('919876543210', "test message");
```

But if I tried sending url type message like

```
$w->sendMessage('919876543210', "http://www.google.com");
```

It gets received as plain text, not hyperlink. 
I tried all options like giving html tags along with text but failed.

Answer (score 3):

In WhatsApp, 
Hyperlinks will be received as text if the Sender Number is not already in contact list of receiver.

However, as soon as the receive adds the sender as their contact, the hyperlink will be clickable.

Comment: well, maybe it is, or should be, i dont know .
Facebook technologies are not simple like that. It works, know if your link is good or not, how many times sent, and a lot of things. Its just not for that spammy shit, and i will report all spam i get. I got only 2 spammy messages this year. The Internet had never spam-free services, as whatsapp and Facebook .

Answer (score 0):

my friend, dont do that .

I think you Will be banned .

If not, already got .