# How send text message with link in WhatsApp using what's API chat

Tags: whatsapp, whatsapi

I am using WhatsApp chat in PHP to send messages. From my PHP script everything work fine, but the URL inside the text message doesn't render as a clickable link. It is shown as plain text instead.

```
$Msg= "hello !. \N http://example.com ";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: May be this answer will help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26365363/sending-hyeprlink-text-through-whatsapp-api-php .

Comment: Refer the Website https://phrkrish.wordpress.com/2016/07/18/share-video-image-text-through-an-ios-app-in-whatsapp/

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP variable is seen as plain text because is a pure string, nothing more.
Your goal is to let be clickable that link and I guess it will be shown in a webpage.
In this case, you should put some HTML code inside that variable.

Starting from your code, a valid solution can be this:

```
$Msg= "hello !. \N <a href='http://example.com "'>Click Here</a>;
```

Otherwise, you can implement this function:

```
    function make_links_clickable($text){
    return preg_replace('!(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $text);
}
```

Answer (score -4):

use some domain mapping for your link..IP will came as plain text

Comment: Please expand your answer. It's sort of hinting around the correct answer but isn't very clear and doesn't really offer anything actionable to the original poster.